# blacklist IP in kubernetes security policy

Tags: security, kubernetes, networking

I read through the kubernetes [network policy documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) and stumbled upon this statement:

> #### What you can't do with network policies (at least, not yet)
>
> The ability to explicitly deny policies (currently the model for NetworkPolicies are deny by default, with only the ability to add allow rules).

Is there a way around this limiting factor or any add on to kubernetes that allows for blacklisting IPs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3rd party for this task.

Few examples:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/restrict-service-external-ip.html
2. https://istio.io/v1.1/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/#ip-based-whitelists-or-blacklists

```yaml
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: listchecker
metadata:
  name: whitelistip
spec:
  # providerUrl: ordinarily black and white lists are maintained
  # externally and fetched asynchronously using the providerUrl.
  overrides: ["10.57.0.0/16"]  # overrides provide a static list
  blacklist: false
  entryType: IP_ADDRESSES
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: listentry
metadata:
  name: sourceip
spec:
  value: source.ip | ip("0.0.0.0")
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: checkip
spec:
  match: source.labels["istio"] == "ingressgateway"
  actions:
  - handler: whitelistip.listchecker
    instances:
    - sourceip.listentry
---
```

3. With nginx

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    
    #
    # This is the relevant part
    #
    
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 49.36.X.X/32
    # depending on the ingress controller version the annotation
    # above may need to be modified to remove the prefix nginx. i.e.
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 49.36.X.X/32
spec:
  rules:
  - host: web.manitestdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web
            port:
              number: 80
```